# Pivot table and combine records onto 1 line

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I've tried many different ways to pivot a table to show all records on 1 row. I've provided my query for the closest solution I came up with. It'll probably be easier if I illustrate what I need. Since there can be an unlimited number of teacher survey questions the query has to be dynamic. I've modified the column names to make it easier to read.

**teacherSurveyQuestions**

```
TSQID    CID    Order    OQReference    Stem
1        1011   1        q1_rb          blabla
2        1011   2        q2_rb          blabla
3        1011   3        q2a_cb         blabla
```

**teacherSurveyUserID**

```
TSUID    firstName    lastName    UID
1        Bob          Smith       1027
2        Tom          Jones       1034
```

**teacherSurveyAnswers**

```
TSAID    UID    TSQID    TSUID    Response
1        1027   1        1        Bob 1
2        1027   2        1        Bob 2
3        1027   3        1        Bob 3
4        1034   1        2        Tom 1
5        1034   2        2        Tom 2
6        1034   3        2        Tom 3
```

Now I need this data to look like this:

```
firstName    lastName    q1_rb    q2_rb    q2a_cb
Bob          Smith       Bob 1    Bob 2    Bob 3
Tom          Jones       Tom 1    Tom 2    Tom 3
```

Here's what I have so far that kind of works except all the responses are NULL

```
declare  @query as nvarchar(max),
         @colsPivot as nvarchar(max)

select @colsPivot = stuff((select ',' 
                           + quotename(OQReference) 
                           from teacherSurveyQuestions tsq
                           where tsq.CID = 1011
                           order by tsq.Order
                    for xml path(''), type
                    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

set @query 
= 'select *
from
  (
    select firstName, lastName, value, col +''_''+ CAST(rn as varchar(10)) as col
    from
      (
       select
         tsu.TSUID  
         ,tsu.firstName
         ,tsu.lastName
         ,tsq.OQReference
         ,tsa.Response
         ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by tsu.TSUID order by tsq.Order) rn
       from teacherSurveyQuestions tsq 
       inner join teacherSurveyAnswers tsa on tsa.TSQID = tsq.TSQID
       inner join teacherSurveyUsers tsu on tsu.TSUID = tsa.TSUID
       where tsq.CID = 1011
   ) x
   unpivot
   (
     value
     for col in (OQReference)
   ) u
  ) x1
  pivot
  (
    max(value)
    for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
  ) p'

exec(@query)
```

Result of query:

```
firstName    lastName    q1_rb    q2_rb    q2a_cb
Bob          Smith       NULL     NULL     NULL
Tom          JOnes       NULL     NULL     NULL
```

Comment: There is a fixed number of questions ? Or, There is a maximum number of questions ? Example: maximum 3 questions.

Comment: There will NOT be a fixed number of questions or a maximum number of questions.

Comment: How is consumed/used this recordset (`firstName, lastName, q1_rb, q2_rb, ...`) ? Do you want to print the result ?

Comment: I'll be using it in a stored procedure which will be output as an excel file, but I just need the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare  @query as nvarchar(max),
         @colsPivot as nvarchar(max)

select @colsPivot = stuff((select ',' 
                           + quotename(OQReference) 
                           from teacherSurveyQuestions tsq
                           where tsq.CID = 1011
                           order by tsq.[Order]
                    for xml path(''), type
                    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
                    ,1,1,'')



set @query 
= 'select firstName, lastName,'+ @colspivot +'
from
  (
    select firstName, lastName,Response, value
    from
      (
       select
         tsu.TSUID  
         ,tsu.firstName
         ,tsu.lastName
         ,tsq.OQReference
         ,tsa.Response
         ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by tsu.TSUID order by tsq.[Order]) rn
       from teacherSurveyQuestions tsq 
       inner join teacherSurveyAnswers tsa on tsa.TSQID = tsq.TSQID
       inner join teacherSurveyUserID tsu on tsu.TSUID = tsa.TSUID
       where tsq.CID = 1011
   ) x
   unpivot
   (
     value
     for col in (OQReference)
   ) u
  ) x1
  pivot
  (
    max(Response)
    for value in ('+ @colspivot +')
  ) p'

exec(@query)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4551a/1)

Comment: I didn't realize how close I was! Thank you.